# Postfix: How to store incoming mail into file and then send it from that file

Tags: postfix

how could I configure postfix so that it store incoming email into file e.g. into network storage.  And then I would like to send that from that file with another postfix server as normal relaying?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mount this network storage on /var/mail and /var/spool/mail you will have all incoming mails stored to the network storage.
The above is true if you do not change the default config of postfix.

Be aware procmail, cyrus-sasl can also handle incoming mail and "move" it around